# cuSolver doesn't return the correct solution

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I'm trying to use the QR linear system solver in cuSOLVER, this

```
#include <cusparse_v2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cusolverSp.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

using namespace thrust;

#define CUSPARSE_CHECK(x) {cusparseStatus_t _c=x; if (_c != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {printf("cusparse fail: %d, line: %d\n", (int)_c, __LINE__); exit(-1);}}

void init_handlers_and_matr_descriptor(cusolverSpHandle_t& cusolverH,cusparseHandle_t& cusparseH,cusparseMatDescr_t& descrA) {
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusolverSpCreate(&cusolverH));
    assert(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusparseCreate(&cusparseH));
    assert(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA)); //CUSPARSE_INDEX_ZERO,CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL
    assert(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA,CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO));
    assert(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
}

int sparse_solver_test() {

    //Init csr format A and b for solving Ax = b
    /*
    A =
    [  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ]
    [  3.0  4.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ]
    [  0.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  0.0  0.0 ]
    [  0.0  0.0  9.0 10.0 11.0  0.0 ]
    [  0.0  0.0  0.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 ]
    [  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 15.0 16.0 ]

    b = [0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0]^T
    */

    int nnz_A = 16, m = 6;

    cusolverSpHandle_t cusolverH = NULL;
    cusparseHandle_t cusparseH = NULL; //cuBLAS or cuSPARSE?
    cusolverStatus_t cusolver_status = CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;
    cudaError_t cudaStat;

    init_handlers_and_matr_descriptor(cusolverH, cusparseH, descrA);

    host_vector<double> h_csrValA(nnz_A), h_dataB(m), h_dataX(m);
    host_vector<int> h_csrRowPtrA(m + 1), h_csrColIndA(nnz_A);
    device_vector<double> d_csrValA(nnz_A), d_dataB(m), d_dataX(m);
    device_vector<int> d_csrRowPtrA(m + 1), d_csrColIndA(nnz_A);

    //Init matrix
    for (auto i = 0; i < nnz_A; ++i) h_csrValA[i] = static_cast<double>(i + 1);
    h_csrRowPtrA[0] = 0;
    h_csrRowPtrA[1] = 2;
    for (auto i = 2; i < m; ++i) h_csrRowPtrA[i] = h_csrRowPtrA[i - 1] + 3;
    h_csrRowPtrA[m] = nnz_A;

    h_csrColIndA[0] = 0;
    int v[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5 };
    for (auto i = 0; i < nnz_A; ++i) h_csrColIndA[i] = v[i];

    for (auto i = 0; i < m; ++i) h_dataB[i] = static_cast<double>(2 * i);

    //device memory and descriptor A init
    d_csrValA = h_csrValA;
    d_csrRowPtrA = h_csrRowPtrA;
    d_csrColIndA = h_csrColIndA;
    d_dataB = h_dataB;

    //step4, solve the linear system?
    int singularity;
    cusolver_status = cusolverSpDcsrlsvqr(
        cusolverH, m, nnz_A, descrA,
        d_csrValA.data().get(), d_csrRowPtrA.data().get(), d_csrColIndA.data().get(), d_dataB.data().get(),
        0.0, 0, d_dataX.data().get(), &singularity);

    std::cout << "singularity = " << singularity << std::endl;
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusolver_status);

    h_dataX = d_dataX;

    std::cout << "x = (";
    for (auto i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        std::cout << h_dataX[i];
        if (i < m - 1) std::cout << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (cusparseH)
        cusparseDestroy(cusparseH);
    if (cusolverH)
        cusolverSpDestroy(cusolverH);
    if (descrA)
        cusparseDestroyMatDescr(descrA);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sparse_solver_test();
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if the setup of my function is wrong, can anyone help?

**Update** I simplified the code a bit using the thrust library, still the error is the same though, but at least I got rid of all the malloc etc...

**Update** Corrected the `csrIndColA` (changed the code accordingly) array as suggested. Now the solver works (i.e. I'm not getting anymore the error I was getting earlier), still though I'm getting 0 as result.

**Update** With all the changes I've done I also forgot to initialize `h_dataB`, together with the indices in `csrIndColA` that solved the problem, the full code is above for future reference.

Comment: Initialization (all those `malloc` and `cudaMalloc`) seems ok, because I can print the values correctly). Trying to check what happens after those initialization.

Comment: The only clue I have is that the variable `singularity` is 0, which means the matrix is not invertible, which is odd because I've just checked and it is invertible.

Comment: What is the value of the returned status for the `cusolverSpDcsrlsvqr` call? according to this http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html there should be a status returned if it is not SUCCESS it could explain what happened.

Comment: `CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`

Comment: Yay.. at least you know why you are not getting a result.. it failed ;) Now we need to figure out why :)

Comment: XD, I got that xD. Is the csr representation I've given correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is beyond my ability. :( I have not done any CUDA dev in years. Hopefully someone can help you further. :(

Comment: CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR


An internal cuSolver operation failed. This error is usually caused by a cudaMemcpyAsync() failure. 
To correct: check that the hardware, an appropriate version of the driver, and the cuSolver library are correctly installed. Also, check that the memory passed as a parameter to the routine is not being deallocated prior to the routine’s completion.

Comment: cuda capabilites 6.1 and the toolkit version is the 9.1.85 (latest). Drivers are latest version as well.

Comment: The synchronization might be the problem tough, in a cuda example there's a call `cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();` which I haven't. Not sure where should I use it though.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine at this point. (probably better actually :) )

Comment: It must be something stupid... I'm 90% sure.

Comment: There are no smart bugs :)...

Comment: Your use of thrust vectors as arguments to the cusolver call is completely wrong

Comment: why is that? Am I not passing the pointer tho the device memory? Can you tell me how to correct it?

Comment: @talonmies I sorted out everything, I'd like to know how I am supposed to use the thrust vectors as arguments.

Comment: raw_pointer_cast is the canonical way to get a pointer from a device_pointer, although is seems like the get() method might work

Answer (score 1):

The `csrColIndA` array in your example is too short, so that cuSOLVER tries to read past the end of it.

[According to the cuSOLVER documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#format-csr) and common convention, the column index array has the same length as the array of nonzero matrix entries, and stores the column index of each nonzero element (and not just the first nonzero element in each column as in your example, which would limit the format to sparsity patterns where all nonzero elements are vertically consecutive).

So your example output should have

```
csrColIndA = {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5}
```

Comment: If this was the error then as I said... it was really stupid... lemme try. Thank you

Comment: Ok, that was an error, but I'm still getting 0 as solution. I can believe I made such a mistake... the error I had with the solver disappeared.

Comment: Ok sorted out, I forgot to initialize the vector `dataB`.